# Get latest item date where item field_1 & item field_2 have duplicates

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm using `Django 4.0`, and `Python 3.8`.

I have a product that has a `modification date`, `department name` and `designation`.

I want to retrieve each product but, for products that have the same designation and the same department, I only want to retrieve the last entry.

Here is what i have now:

```
products = Product.objects.all().order_by('designation')
```

I tried sorting on the result and removing duplicate rows it worked for 10 rows but for 100 its dead

For the following data:

item: designation, date, department

1. item_1, 01/01/1970, department_1
2. item_2, 01/01/1970, department_2
3. item_3, 01/01/1970, department_3
4. item_1, 01/02/1970, department_1

I want:

1. item_1, 01/02/1970, department_1
2. item_2, 01/01/1970, department_2
3. item_3, 01/01/1970, department_3

Do you have any advice please ?

edit: department is another model, and the relationship between product and department is Many to Many.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a PostgreSQL database, use the `distinct()` method on your QuerySet ([link to Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)) to "eliminate duplicate rows from the query results".

In your case:

```py
products = Product.objects.all().order_by('designation', 'department').distinct('designation', 'department')
```

If you're using another database, you can use `distinct()` as well but without passing positional arguments (`*fields`).

Comment: These aren't really duplicate rows because they have a different date, and I only want the last one. 
I tried:
Product.objects.filter(department=department).order_by('designation', 'department').distinct('designation', 'department').latest('date')

but got django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Comment: If you're using PostgreSQL, try `Product.objects.filter(department=department).order_by('designation', 'department', 'date').distinct('designation', 'department')`

Comment: Perfect, thank you, I just added a '-' before 'date', to be sure to have the latest.